# Django ManytoMany data population on website

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have 2 table inside my Django, where one is ManytoMany from another, like below:

```
TABLE1          TABLE2           TABLE_3
ID    Item1     ID    Item2      ID     TABLE1_ID     TABLE2_ID
1     a         1     o          1      1             2
2     b         2     p          2      2             3
3     c         3     q          3      3             1
```

Now I try to print a table as below to my index:

```
Item1      Item2
a          p
b          q
c          o
```

I am wondering how Can I make it work? I am stuck here for some time... please help.

I try to use 2 List data as:

```
TABLE1_List = TABLE1.objects.all()
TABLE2_List = TABLE2.objects.all()
```

in my templates file, I try to use:

```
<table>
{% for t1 in TABLE1_List %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{t1.Item1}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<table>
{% for t2 in TABLE2_List %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{t2.Item2}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This will return 2 table for me, but how can I join them into one table?
Please kindly help! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to post my solution here: I have set 2 list as tuple list in views as below:

```
TABLE=list(zip(T1,T2))
```

and use the following cold in templates:

```
{% for t1,t2 in TABLE %}
     <tr>
          <td>t1.item1</td>
          <td>t2.item2</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same number of items in both columns, something like this this may work. (not tested)

```
<table>
{% for t1 in TABLE1_List %}
{% for t2 in TABLE2_List %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{t1.Item1}}</td>
       <td>{{t2.Item2}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}    
</table>
```

**Edit:** after thinking about it, I think you would be better placing two tables next to each other. Or just use DIV tags etc.

Comment: That's no wrok... it will generate 3*3 rows... the For loop is not in parallel. Is there any other way we can do? thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to post my solution here: I have set 2 list as tuple list in views, and use the following cold in templates: {% for t1,t2 in TABLE %}. Thanks a lot for inspiration.